# How to combine several XSLT transformations?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>A title of the article</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px; }

body > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0 !important; }
body > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>The page is an article about an article.</p>
  <p>This paragraph is not very good paragraph</p>
  <p>This paragraph is very good paragraph</p>
  <h4 id="toc_0">Page content</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>An itroduction</li>
    <li>An inline piece of code <code>select * from dual</code></li>
    <li>Buttons <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <pre>
      <code class="language-none">select * from dual
      </code>
    </pre>
  </div>

  <h4 id="toc_1">Usage</h4>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Page ID</th>
        <th>Page name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>Page number 1234</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>5678</td>
        <td>Page number 5678</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>90AB</td>
        <td>Page number 90AB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to do the following:

1. Replace tags `code` and `kbd` with `span`
2. Add a class to each new `span` with previous tag name (i. e. `<code> ... </code>` should be transformed into `<span class="code"> ... </span>`, etc.)
3. Keep the content of tag `body` and remove the rest.

I found how to make this partially. This transformation makes steps 1 and 2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <span class="code"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kbd">
        <span class="kbd"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transformation makes step 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/html/body">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But each transformation does only its job. I can either replace tags, or cut the content of a `body`. I tried to combine this transformations, but failed.
Also, the second transformation doesn't add a class, if it already was there. For example, this

```
<code class="language-none">
```

turns into this

```
<span class="language-none">
```

while I would like to have the following (the sequence of class names doesn't matter):

```
<span class="language-none code">
```

And there is an annoying thing. When a source file contains the line

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

then I get an error "invalid XML". OK, I agree it's invalid, but after the second transformation my utility (I use a command-line utility xsltproc on Mac) inserts exactly the same line into the result file.

Comment: If the root element of the result document is `html` then the processor assumes you want the `xsl:output method="html"` and inserts/adds that `meta` element and does that in HTML syntax. If you want to create intermediary X(HT)ML you would need to set `<xsl:output method="xml"/>`, then you don't get the `meta` and the XSLT result is serialized according to XML rules and can be further processed by XML tools (like XSLT processors). You might want to check `xsltproc` features, it is based on libxml and libxslt and I think its developers introduced some ways to process HTML instead of XML.

Comment: As for the other problems, which final output result do you want, is the output supposed to be an XML or HTML fragment without a common `html` root element, with all those `p` and `ul` and other children of the input's `body` as top level sibling elements?

Comment: As for `meta` element in the source file: if any possibility to ignore it exists, it would be great. As for result file: if is enough to save the result into a file with any root element (`html` is also OK), content of `body` tag shouldn't change except transformations in pp. 1 and 2 in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the three steps you can write templates for `html` and `body` that just process the children, for `html/head` that does nothing and then you need to find some way to add your new class and keep the existing, here is one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="html | html/body">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="html/head"/>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <span class="{@class} code"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'class')] | node()" /></span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kbd">
        <span class="{@class} kbd"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'class')] | node()" /></span>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqd

Comment: Thanks! Exactly as I wanted!